Sallen key second order design
I am trying to design a second-order Sallen-Key low-pass filter with gain, but I must admit I’m a bit confused. Let's assume my goal is to have a cutoff frequency of 1 kHz, with a gain of 10 and a quality factor Q of 0.707.

Source: OKAWA Electric Design. 
The generalized transfer function for a 2nd-order low-pass filter is

source: blog.mbedded.ninja
where fc and Q are given by

source: blog.mbedded.ninja
So seems like increasing the gain, k = 1 + (R4/R3), can result in a higher quality factor
Q, potentially making the filter unstable. Appears that we need to find appropriate ratios between 1/2 and 1/2. How can we determine those ratio values?

Those formulas for $f_c$ and Q are not correct. You can see this from the fact that the dimensions are wrong. Q should be dimensionless, and $f_c$ should have dimensions of 1/sec

The term R1R2C1C2 should be under a square root symbol in both equations. They were copied from the specified website which also lacks the square roots

Hmmm. Looks like that ninja website has the sqrt coded in the html but fails to render it and puts a blank space instead. The 1st link you have shows the correct $f_c$ equation.

Jeep, you aren't getting a gain of 10. Not in the Sallen-Key topology there. Gain and damping factor/Q are mutually dependent on gain and there is no way to get more than a gain of 3, memory serving. And you have to trade off on the Q to get there.

I think, the mentioned gain restriction (below three) applies to the "equal-component" topology only. Of course, you can build a Sallen-Key lowpass with higher gain values (for example: Acl=10) - however you have to pay with a rather large component spread. This will lead to higher parts tolerances and realization problems (range of preferred parts values). Note that this filter topology (especially the pole-Q value) is rather sensitive to these non-idealities. For these reasons, other structures (MFB or GIC-based) are recommended for gain values above two.

Your expectations of a Sallen Key filter with gain are fundamentally flawed. Basically, if you have "high gain" and equal value resistors and capacitors, the quality factor zooms away and turns your circuit into an oscillator for gains greater than three. To combat this we reduce the Q accordingly so that the feedback capacitor doesn't cause the problem. But then we are left with a rubbish Q factor and usually an undesirable performance.
The better solution in these circumstances is to use an MFB 2nd order filter. It can handle high gain and decent Q values.

I'd like to add a few quick thoughts to consider in this particular circuit.
$$
\begin{align*}
K&=1+\frac{R_3}{R_4}&\omega_{_0}&=\frac1{\sqrt{R_1\,R_2\,C_1\,C_2}}&Q&=\frac{\sqrt{R_1\,R_2\,C_1\,C_2}}{R_1\,C_2+R_2\,C_2-R_1\, C_1\frac{R_3}{R_4}}
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\text{Your version of the standard form can also be expressed as,}\\\\
\begin{align*}
H_s&=K\cdot\frac1{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2+\frac1{Q}\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)+1}
\end{align*}
$$
Note that \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$ only show themselves in the equation for \$Q\$. Otherwise, they affect nothing at all.
That can be reworded, in a sense, by noting that  \$\frac{R_3}{R_4}=K-1\$. So \$Q=\frac{\sqrt{R_1\,R_2\,C_1\,C_2}}{R_1\,C_2+R_2\,C_2-R_1\, C_1\cdot\left(K-1\right)}\$.
That's how the gain gets inserted and shows itself affecting \$Q\$. It's just another way of saying that \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$ affect \$Q\$, and only \$Q\$.
There are many approaches one can take. Raonoke takes one of them by taking \$R_1=R_2\$. But I'd like to introduce another approach that starts with a different simplifying idea.
One important criteria for a circuit like this is the loading it imposes on the source driving it. For example, it may be known in advance that the input impedance be \$\ge 10\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Setting \$R_1\$ is then an obvious and easily seen target. Also, note that \$\tau=R_1\,C_1\$ multiplies \$K-1\$ in the expression for \$Q\$.
Choosing to simplify design by asserting that \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{R_1\,C_1}=\frac1{\tau}\$ helps in several ways. First, it sets up a very simple way, 1st order in a sense, to see this 2nd order circuit. And that's a nice thing. Once \$R_1\$ is picked to approximate a designed input impedance it's then very easy to calculate \$C_1\$. And this cracks open the circuit and makes the rest fall apart in nice pieces.
I think (personal opinion) that this is better than just assigning \$R_1=R_2\$ as  Raonoke did because a 1st order approximation of a 2nd order circuit has real value.
Given \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{\tau}\$ and also that \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{\sqrt{\tau\,R_2\,C_2}}\$, then \$\frac1{\tau}=\frac1{\sqrt{\tau\,R_2\,C_2}}\$ and very simple manipulation arrives at \$\tau=R_2\,C_2\$, too. So once this decision is taken then it must also be that \$R_2\,C_2=R_1\,C_1\$.
This still leaves some freedom because one can adjust \$R_2\$ in one direction by adjusting \$C_2\$ in the opposite direction. And this allows changes in ratios. And that is important for allowing user-selection of \$K\$ in this circuit!
The fact that \$R_2\,C_2=R_1\,C_1\$ allows us to say that \$\sqrt{R_1\,R_2\,C_1\,C_2}=R_1\,C_1=\tau\$
So let's see where that goes:
$$\begin{align*}
Q&=\frac{\sqrt{R_1\,R_2\,C_1\,C_2}}{R_1\,C_2+R_2\,C_2-R_1\, C_1\cdot\left(K-1\right)}
\\\\
&=\frac{R_1\,C_1}{R_1\,C_2+R_2\,C_2-R_1\,C_1\cdot\left(K-1\right)}
\\\\
&=\frac1{\frac{C_2}{C_1}+2-K}
\end{align*}$$
And that's cool! Here, the ratio of \$r_{_\text{C}}=\frac{C_2}{C_1}\$ shows itself! And note that the ratio of \$r_{_\text{R}}=\frac{R_2}{R_1}\$ doesn't even appear. It's gone. So the focus is only on this ratio and that keeps design simple. \$R_2\$ will just fall out as a consequence and isn't a separate unknown!
This is a good place to stop for a moment and see what's there. Note that I'd said in comments about a gain of \$K=3\$. This applies here when \$C_1=C_2\$. In that case, the above immediately shows the problem for \$K=3\$ (0 in the divisor!)
However, now it is also much more obvious how a higher gain can be achieved, by making \$C_2\gt C_1\$. Then \$r_{_\text{C}}=K-2+\frac1{Q}\$. For a gain of \$K=10\$ and \$Q=\frac12\sqrt{2}\$ then it follows that \$r_{_\text{C}}=8+\sqrt{2}\$ and \$r_{_\text{R}}=\frac1{8+\sqrt{2}}\$.
Let's give that a whirl:

Looks pretty good, I think.
Hopefully, this provides a direct answer to your question about ratios and a methodology that keeps the viewpoint focused on a simpler 1st order view, while allowing just enough flexibility to accommodate reasonable design goals.

Wow, I spent more than 45 minutes figuring out and grasping this solution, but it was definitely worth it! It’s much clearer now, thank you so much, It was extremely helpful!


So seems like increasing the gain, k = 1 + (R4/R3), can result in a higher quality factor Q, potentially making the filter unstable. Appears that we need to find appropriate ratios between 1/2 and 1/2. How can we determine those ratio values?

Only the capacitors C1/C2 have to be adjusted depending upon the required gain. Keep everything else (R1/R2/Q/fc) the same. To simplify things make R1 = R2, with Q = 0.7071 and fc = 1kHz.
Unity gain 2nd order S&K lowpass filter:

2nd order S&K lowpass filter with a gain Av = 1 + R3/R4 = 10.


C1/C2 are calculated from:
w0 = 2 * Pi * fc = 1 / SQR(R1 * R2 * C1 * C2)
2 * Q / w0 = (R1 + R2) * C1 - (Av - 1) * R2 * C2
For a gain Av = 1 + R3/R4 = 10 and R1 = R2 = R the equations simplify to:
w0 = 2 * Pi * fc = 1 / [R * SQR(C1 * C2)]
2 * Q / w0 = 2 * R * C1 - 9 * R * C2

Good answer. Thanks. My recollections were about a common choice with equal-valued resistor and capacitor values. So +1 for this. And I'm going to add an answer when I get a moment, just to add a few more re-awakened thoughts given that you've chosen to make $R_1=R_2$. There's many ways to slice this where that isn't true. Thanks!
